# Is there any way to change the scope of a callback without changing the paramaters?

Tags: c++, callback

I am using SDL2_mixer library, but I believe that the question should hold for the general case also.

Currently, a function that I would like to use, `Mix_HookMusicFinished(void (*music_finished)(void))` has a set callback to the global scope for a C style function. However, I would like to have that callback be set to a member function within my own class `void CMusic::musicFinished()` without having the need for a function in global scope.

Is there anyway to do this? Something like `Mix_HookMusicFinished(musicFinished)` would be great, but that directly has an error of `argument of type "void (CMusic::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)()"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a "wrapper" function. However, the problem here is that you also need to be able to find the `CMusic` object that you want to "finish" - this is really what the crux of

> argument of type ... is incompatible with ...

is all about. Since there is no way to pass a parameter to the `musicFinished` object, you will need some other way of "finding" the `CMusic` object.

If we assume there is a way to do that, then something like this would work:

```
class CMusic 
{
   ... 

 public:
   ...
   static void musicFinishedWrapper();
   void musicFinished();
   ...
};


void CMusic::musicFinishedWrapper()
{
   CMusic* music = getTheMusicSomehow();   // No idea how you do this - depends on your code. 

   music->musicFinished();
}
```

The reason you have to have a CMusic object is that your `musicFinished` expects a (hidden) `this` pointer argument - which is the value in `music` in my little function.

Answer (score 1):

You could move `musicFinished` to your `CMusic` class and declare it as a `static` class method.  `static` class methods aren't called on an object; they therefore don't have an implicit argument to specify the value of the `this` pointer, and they therefore can have the same signature as freestanding functions.  You additionally can make it `private` to prevent anything but `CMusic` from using it.

However, since your `musicFinished` method currently works as a freestanding function and therefore probably doesn't need access to `CMusic`'s `protected` or `private` members, and since your efforts to limit its scope presumably means that you don't want other things to call it, I personally would leave your `musicFinished` function as freestanding but declare it as `static` (or move it to an anonymous namespace, if you prefer) within the `CMusic` source (`.cpp` or `.cc`) file.  Doing so would restrict its scope to the source file (the "compilation unit").  An advantage over a `private`, `static` class method is that it does not need to be exposed at all in a header file, so it is in some sense more private.